# Best practices for persisting user credentials in a Backbone.js based app?

Tags: spring-mvc, backbone.js, spring-security

I have a Backbone based app, which uses a Spring based backend.

The backend is secured using Spring security's implementation of http basic authentication and the user credentials are passed to the server in each request in accordance to REST.

Is there a secure way to store the credentials in the client?

I have tried several server based approaches, like remember-me feature, but it doesn't work with basic authentication, nor does it fit the definition of REST.

Answer (score 2):

I've used cookies to hold on to user credentials object and that doesn't work too badly for the most part, although it can get a bit messy, and I'm not 100% sure how secure it is.

Store your user authentication in a cookie, and check for it when the router gets initialized. If the data is there, throw your authentication information onto your global application object `app.user` or something of the like.